# CSS overflow: auto hiding tooltip

Tags: html, css

I have a tooltip which gets hidden due to `overflow: auto` on the parent div.

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="item"><span class="tooltip">Tooltip text</span></div>
        <div class="item"><span class="tooltip">Tooltip text</span></div>
        <div class="item"><span class="tooltip">Tooltip text</span></div>
    </div>
</div>

#wrapper {
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
.item {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
.item:hover .tooltip {
    visibility: visible;
}
.item .tooltip {
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 0;
    border-radius: 6px;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

[JSfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/user1212/22836uoL/#)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the `position: absolute;` to `position: fixed;` in `tooltip` class